# Strange error in XCode8.2

Tags: xcode8

I have installed latest xcode8.2 and when I tried to build, I am getting a strange error "Failed to launch IBCocoaTouch ImageCatalogTool via Core Simulator spawn". The same project works in another laptop at the same time. I am not able to go forward. Can anyone give some suggestion?

Comment: Will you please add you console?

Comment: Also clean your project and then try.